# Ever since I upgraded to 16.04, Chrome logs me out of sites with every reboot. What gives?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, upgrade, login, google-chrome

Running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with Gnome version 3.20.4.

Since the upgrade, Chrome doesn't seem to keep me logged in on a bunch of sites. Weirdly enough, not all websites are affected. For example, I stay logged in on reddit, but I have to manually login on twitch after every reboot.
Login info for affected sites is still saved and available, I can still fill the login fields with autocorrect.

I assume it has something to do with the OS' key management, but I never really understood that system, so I'm kinda at a loss here.

**Edit:** Some people have marked this question as an "exact duplicate" of a similar question, but it isn't, because:

1) The other user is getting logged out of *all* website logins *and* his Chrome account. I am only getting logged out from *some* website logins, and I do stay logged in on my Chrome account.

2) I've already tried the solution from the other thread and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have been having similiar problems on Linux Mint 18 using Chromium browser. Browser logs me out of my profile on each reboot. Regrettably haven't gotten around to fixing it yet. Will try and remember to post a  solution if I find one, in the hope that it also might fix things for you.